# Is there any GraphQL schema docs generator like swagger in python?

Tags: python, documentation, graphql, graphene-python

I'm using graphene-python for my flask based graphQL server. and I want to use docs generator from code like swagger.

I've searched it from google, but got nothing. Is there any  GraphQL schema docs generator from code for python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [graphiql](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) - graphical interactive in-browser GraphQL IDE that is comes handy to explore API.

Comment: i already know that. but i want to find much better docs generator.

Comment: apparently there is none? Can't find any other option out there

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63843954/9671997 TLDR; better use built-in docs as they're inreractive, but there is some tools like https://github.com/2fd/graphdoc#readme